# What is exact replacement statement in Get2D in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I am unable to find out a proper replacement statement for the get2D function. I am trying to convert a code in cv to cv2.

```
_,src = capture.read() 
src = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.UMat(src),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.setMouseCallback("camera",on_mouse, 0);
s=cv.Get2D(hsv,y_co,x_co)
```

If I convert by typing

```
s = hsc[y_co,x_co]
```

then I get the error

```
TypeError: 'cv2.UMat' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Please suggest a solution

Comment: If you want to access the data, you have to convert the `UMat` back to a numpy array: `cv2.UMat.get(hsv)`

Comment: My question was what do I replaced the Get2D line of code with? Please let me know.

Comment: You'd do exactly what you tried. That was the right idea. The problem is that you're using `UMat` which is a special data type to allow you to take advantage of OpenCL. `UMat` doesn't let you access the data directly. After you convert it back to a regular numpy array (which is the Python equivalent to `Mat`), you can use indexing to access the individual pixels.

Comment: Or you can just replace the `cv2.UMat(src)` in the second line by a simple `src`. But that means you'll no longer be using the Transparent API (and therefore any OpenCL accelerated implementations of various OpenCV functions). In this particular example, it probably won't matter (maybe will even make it faster, since you don't do much work to compensate for the various overheads).